# Retrieve keras model fit history afer execution interrupt

Tags: python, keras

In a jupyter notebook, I'm doing a training in keras with a line similar to

```
history = model.fit(....., epoch=100)
```

When I see that `var_loss` converge I break manually the execution, and obviously history is not returned.

Is there a way to retrieve it? A member of model, or method, or a way to get the history object or its members?

Comment: @Mq how do you stop the execution - with a KeyboardInterrupt? Did you ever solve this i.e. figure out how to get the exception trapped by the callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Mquinteiro Try using a callback: https://keras.io/callbacks/. You could set the callback to terminate when the model is no longer improving (`keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping`) and then access the best model (`save_best_only = True`), or you could have the callback save checkpoints after each epoch (`keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint`) which you can access after manually stopping the execution.

Comment: How does one retrieve the history in this scenario? Should the a custom callback save the model?

Answer (score 2):

I tested with Tensorflow v2.9.2 and `history` is an attribute on the model even if the training was interrupted (and without setting an explicit callback) when compiling the model.

For example, if interrupting a keras train like

```py
history = model.fit(train_dataset, validation_data=val_dataset, 
                    epochs=25, verbose=1)
```

, the history is accessible via `model.history`:

```py
history = model.history

plt.plot(history.history["loss"])
plt.title("Training Loss")
plt.ylabel("loss")
plt.xlabel("epoch")
plt.show()
```